# Systemd shutting down when terminal is closed

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

My systemd service file is in the name of `os.service` and has the following line of configuration.

```
#  This systemd service file will help supervise os service
[Unit]
Description=Os Server
After= network.target

[Service]

# Preferably configure a non-privileged user
# User=deploy
# Group=deploy

# Environment variables shared across the config
#EnvironmentFile=  # environment file to be used, includes RACK_ENV
EnvironmentFile=/home/deploy/test/shared/.env
SyslogIdentifier=test
PIDFile=/home/deploy/test/shared/tmp/server.pid

# Specify the path to your test application root
# WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/test/

# Start/Reload/Stop syntax
ExecStart=/home/deploy/test/current

# TimeoutSec=15
# TimeoutStopSec=10
RestartSec=5s           

# Restart os, always if it dies for some reason
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In server when I disconnect my ssh connection then service dies and results in **502 Bad Gateway**. I have to ssh and run `systemctl --user start os.service` to start and make it work. Again once i close my terminal then os.service dies again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re running the service from your user manager (`--user`), and apparently your `logind` doesn’t have lingering enabled for you. As a result, your session (including any services started inside it) is closed down whenever you log out.

To change this behaviour, you need to [enable lingering](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html#enable-linger%20USER%E2%80%A6):

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger $USER
```

This will start a user manager for you at boot and allow your services to survive your login sessions.

A better approach for a system service such as this is really to run it as its own user, managed by the main systemd instance.

Comment: Thanks. That solved!!!!. I used command `loginctl enable-linger $USER` and close my ssh connection server and systemd service is running fine.