# Debian 11, 12 and Ubuntu 22.04 terminate screen root processes when started from console (tty) on logout but not Debian 10 nor Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: debian, gnu-screen

When starting processes due to screen via console, those get killed on logout.

```bash
login: root
password: ***
```

then starting some command:

```bash
screen -d -S sample -m bash -c '/hom/app/server start'
```

After this the service is running and screen shows that process

```bash
screen -ls

# output
# There are screens on:
#   1805.sample (01/05/24 12:13:18) (Detached)
# 1 Sockets in /run/screen/S-root.
```

But when I logout, also the screen session will be destroyed.

Doing the same via `ssh` on the same machine by root (with RootLoginPermit) evrything runs on also after logout.

I tested the same actions on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.

It works with no issues on Ubuntu 20.04 also when started by console session.

But it doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04 neither on console.

It is a problem on Debian (tested bullseye and bookworm with latest updates) and Ubuntu (tested 22.04).

All found solutions like `KillUserProcesses=no` are checked and set by default. I also installed a fresh new debian with the same behaviour.

---

On debian and ubuntu it is always the same screen version `Screen version 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20`

---

## UBUNTU

1. Doing a fresh install from Ubuntu 20.04
2. Running screen in detached mode
3. logout and login again
4. screen processes still there

5. Doing an Ubuntu release upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04
6. Running screen in detached mode
7. logout and login again
8. screen processes are killed

---

## DEBIAN

1. Doing a fresh install from Debian 10
2. Running screen in detached mode
3. logout and login again
4. screen processes still there

5. Doing an Debian release upgrade to Debian 11
6. Running screen in detached mode
7. logout and login again
8. screen processes are killed

---

So there is some significant, but currently to me unknown, change in the releases.

Comment: Is [lingering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522554/86440) enabled?

Comment: Hi @StephenKitt - after (re-)enabling lingering it does not change anything. If I run `loginctl list-sessions` on console (/dev/tty1), it prints `no sessions`

Comment: I rechecked on fresh installed Ubuntus - Ubuntu 20.04 works out of the box, Ubuntu 22.04 shows same issue as Debian 11 and 12